# Are bond ETFs considered low risk in this market?

Tags: etf, bonds, risk, risk-management

I'm thinking about moving my money to an automated management service.  I've set my risk profile to 3.5 (low) which means they would invest around 35% in bond ETFs.

With today's interest rates being historically low, why would bond ETFs still be considered a low risk investment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the strictest sense, there are bills,notes, and bonds, named when issued based on their time to maturity. Even though it's called a bond ETF it may have a duration short enough to be made of T-bills, less than a year to maturity.

Simply put, for bonds, risk comes from the duration, time to maturity.

Comment: Isn't there default risk too?

Comment: Yes. Given the very general nature of the question I was answering as if it were a U.S. Government bond ETF, in which case, we treat the default risk as near zero.

Comment: And for company bonds from the "credit grade"?